Coin flip and Die Roll Game Win Probability
Players A and B both start at position $0$. A 6-sided die is rolled, let this number be $D$. A fair coin is flipped. If H shows, then A advances $D$ steps forward. B advances $D$ steps forward if T shows. The above process repeats until a player advances 10 steps then they win. What is the probability B wins?
My initial thought is 50%, because each player has an equal chance of advancing the same number of steps, with symmetric winning conditions.
Can anyone confirm if this is correct?

So the die rolls are repeated? As written, none of them can reach ten steps in one roll. Does it need to be exactly $10,$ or is more allowed?

Hey I've gone and edited the question so it's hopefully a bit more clear now. But the answer is - yes, the process repeats until 1 of them reaches 10 or more

Seems like it has to be 50% by symmetry, as no ties are possible and swapping the players changes nothing.

Your assumption is correct, each has 50% probability of winning (as symmetry suggests).
There are a number of ways this can be modeled (including enumeration by a computer program since the event space is finite). If we can show the probability distributions for the score of each player are equal after each roll, then we know it is a fair game. Let $D\sim \text{Disc Unif}(N=6)$ and $C\sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$. The moment generating function for a single roll is easy to calculate for each player, since they each have 1/2 chance of scoring 0 and 1/12 chance of scoring each 1 through 6:
$$M_{A_1}(t)=M_{B_1}(t)=\text{E}[e^{tx}]=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6e^{it}$$
For multiple rolls, the process repeats with the scores from each independent roll summing, and so for $N$ rolls we obtain the following MGFs:
$$M_A(t)=M_B(t)=\prod_{j=1}^N M_{A_1}=\prod_{j=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6e^{it}\right)$$
Since the MGFs for players $A$ and $B$ are the same for any number of rolls, and since an MGF completely defines a probability distribution, we know the probabilities for the scores for players $A$ and $B$ are equal after every roll. Hence this is a fair game with 50/50 probability of winning for each player.
